# How to properly extend FutureTask

Tags: java, executorservice, swingworker, futuretask

While coding a computation-heavy application, I tried to make use of the SwingWorker class to spread the load to multiple CPU cores. However, behaviour of this class proved to be somewhat strange: only one core seemed to be utilized.

When searching the internet, I found an excellent answer on this web (see [Swingworker instances not running concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548253/swingworker-instances-not-running-concurrently/7548506#7548506), answer by user268396) which -- in addition to the cause of the problem -- also mentions a possible solution:

> What you can do to get around this is use an ExecutorService and post
>   FutureTasks on it. These will provide 99% of the SwingWorker API
>   (SwingWorker is a FutureTask derivative), all you have to do is set up
>   your Executor properly.

Being a Java beginner, I am not entirely sure how to do this properly. Not only that I need to pass some initial data to the FutureTask objects, I also need to get the results back similarly as with SwingWorker. Any example code would therefore be much appreciated.

nvx

==================== EDIT ====================

After implementing the simple yet elegant solution mentioned in [FutureTask that implements Callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468598/futuretask-that-implements-callable), another issue has come up. If I use an `ExecutorService` to create individual threads, how do I execute specific code after a thread finished running?

I tried to override done() of the `FutureTask` object (see the code below) but I guess that the "show results" bit (or any GUI related stuff for that matter) should be done in the application's event dispatch thread (EDT). Therefore: how do I submit the runnable to the EDT?

```
package multicoretest;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MultiCoreTest {

    static int coresToBeUsed = 4;
    static Future[] futures = new Future[coresToBeUsed];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(coresToBeUsed);
        for (int i = 0; i < coresToBeUsed; i++) {
            futures[i] = execSvc.submit(new Worker(i));
        }
        execSvc.shutdown();

        // I do not want to block the thread (so that users can
        // e.g. terminate the computation via GUI)
        //execSvc.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    }

    static class Worker implements Callable<String> {

        private final FutureTask<String> futureTask;
        private final int workerIdx;

        public Worker(int idx) {
            workerIdx = idx;
            futureTask = new FutureTask<String>(this) {
                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            showResults(workerIdx);
                        }
                    };

                    r.run(); // Does not work => how do I submit the runnable
                             // to the application's event dispatch thread?

                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 2e4; i++) {
                s += String.valueOf(i) + " ";
            }
            return s;
        }

        final String get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            return futureTask.get();
        }

        void showResults(int idx) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Worker " + idx + ":" +
                        (String)futures[idx].get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check whether it helps or not. check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808776/extending-futuretask-how-to-handle-cancel

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it. In the meantime I found [a topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468598/futuretask-that-implements-callable) here which seems to be another way of achieving what I need (even though I would need to create an additional abstract class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:

- you rarely need to use FutureTask directly,  just implement Callable or Runnable and submit the instance to an Executor
- in order to update the gui when you are done, as the last step of your `run()`/`call()` method, use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` with the code to update the ui.

Note, you *can* still use `SwingWorker`, just, instead of calling `execute()`, submit the SwingWorker to your Executor instead.

if you need to process all results together when all threads are done before updating the gui, then i would suggest:

- have each worker stash it's results into a thread-safe, shared list
- the *last* worker to add results to the list should then do the post-processing work
- the worker which did the post-processing work should then invoke `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` with the final results

Comment: Thank you, I will try the .invokeLater() approach. As for submitting `SwingWorker`s to an `ExecutorService`, I tried that and it resulted in utilization of a single CPU core only (to be precise: the load was balanced between all cores, but the actual load corresponded to a single core -- e.g. roughly 12% for an eight-core CPU).

Comment: @nvx - then you probably did something wrong with your executor service, or your jobs don't do enough to use multiple cores.

Comment: I've been tinkering with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` since yesterday but -- even though it does work -- it is not an ideal solution. The reason is that I am forced to do post-processing of the results _before_ they are returned to the main thread which is unfortunate, since I absolutely need to do this _en bloc_ for results from all the worker threads. Originally, I wanted to implement `FutureTask`s due to their capability to execute code after a task is done. Is something like this possible directly via an `ExecutorService` object?

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to make use of the SwingWorker class to spread the load to
>   multiple CPU cores. However, behaviour of this class proved to be
>   somewhat strange: only one core seemed to be utilized.

- no idea without posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable,
- [SSCCE could be based on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6174462/714968)
- `SwingWorker` is designated creating `Workers Thread` for Swing GUI, [more in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900697/why-does-swingworker-stop-unexpectedly)